# выполнение скрипта после перезагрузки страницы

Tags: javascript, jquery

есть данный скрипт:

```
$(function() {
    var $categoryWrap = $('#categoryWrap');

        $categoryWrap.on('change', 'select', function () {

        var $this = $(this),
            category_id = this.value;

        $('#categoryIdInput').val(category_id);
        $this.nextAll().remove();

        if(category_id == '0') {
            $('#typeCategory').remove();
            $('#fieldsAdvert').remove();
            return false;
        }

        $.ajax({
            url: 'index.php?route=ajax/SubCategoryList',
            data: {
                id_cat: category_id
            },
            type: 'POST',
            success: function(data) {
                $('#typeCategory').remove();
                $('#fieldsAdvert').remove();
                if (data != '') {
                    var $newSelect = $('<select name="subCategory[]" class="subCategory" data-id="' + category_id + '"/>');
                    $newSelect.append('<option value="0">- <?=$text_select?> -</option>')

                    $.map(data, function(v) {
                        $newSelect.append('<option value="' + v.id + '">' + v.title + '</option>')
                    });
                    $categoryWrap.append($newSelect);
                }
            }
        });
    });
});
```

который прекрасно работает, но, только после полной загрузки сайта, как мне сделать чтоб этот же скрипт работал так же и при ПЕРЕзагрузки сайта?

Comment: Use the `localstorage`, Luke!

Comment: мне не подходит вариант с localstorage но спасибо

Comment: "Не подходит" - довольно слабый аргумент. Разбивается этим: "Чойта?".

Comment: Прошу прощения, а что не так? После F5 скрипт внезапно перестает работать?

Comment: @Other "Тойта" что мне не нужно с помощью этого скрипта оперировать какими-то данными и сохранять их а мне нужно чтоб после перезагрузки страницы (простите за простонародность) браузер видел что был выбран option у select в блоке <div id="categoryWrap"></div> есть такие функции как each, я не знаю как правильно начало этотого кода написать с each или мне нужно дублировать код и писать each??

Comment: @vkt А откуда скрипт будет знать что нужно выбрать без каких-либо сохраненных данных? Магия какая-то. Запоминаете какое поле вам нужно через кукки или локальное хранилище и добавляете в нему `selected`.

Comment: всем спасибо и прошу прощения что не написал сразу, но вопрос можно закрыть, я разобрался